# RegEx: How to find instance of new class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, search

I am working on old large pieces of code that directly create struts 1 actions, because it places logic in there.

I wish to find instances where the action classes are created directly in the code. For instance, say I have MoveAction, UpAction, DownAction. How would I find these using regular expressions, where instances of those classes are created? I need something similar to

```
new *Action()
```

That will not match new ActionMessages()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new .*Action(` should match "new " followed by anything up to "Action("

Comment: Thank you, a little modification of that worked nicely. new .*Action\\(

Answer (score 2):

you can select the constructor of Action in the eclipse IDE and press `ctrl+h` to find all occurrences within your project

```
public Action()/*select the constructor in the class file */{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know of this cool feature. I do prefer the search, though.